# How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I'd like to share a photo with caption pre-filled from my app via a share intent, on facebook.

I know how to share photo or how to share text, but how do I share them together?

Example code

```
Intent shareCaptionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareCaptionIntent.setType("image/*");

    //set photo
    shareCaptionIntent.setData(examplePhoto);
    shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, examplePhoto);

    //set caption
    shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "example caption");
    shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "example caption");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareCaptionIntent,getString(R.string.share)));
```

If a set type to `image/*` then a photo is uploaded without the caption prefilled. If a set it to `text/plain` only the caption is uploaded without the photo.....

---

My guess is that the issue is that the Android Facebook App doesn't look for `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` when it filters an `ACTION_SEND` Intent with type `image/*` for photo uploading. **So this issue could be resolved if the Android Facebook App looked for that value, and if present, inserted it as the caption of the image.**

[image: Share caption via Android Intent]

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @ekawas I haven't. The official facebook app doesn't support text on sharing a photo. And alternative solution I found is to integrate the facebook api into your app and share the photo with caption through that, but that's a lot more complicated than intents.

Comment: Also, I'm not that keen on having a separate menu button just to share on Facebook, while other apps, such as Twitter, Gmail, Flickr do support the generic share intent for photos with caption.

Comment: Have you tried using an archive mime type, such as application/zip and put the image and text inside? I wonder how that would be handled?

Comment: @may i know how can i share image or text in facebook in programatically

Comment: How is it that you set the photo with facebook, I have it working with twitter, instagram, falcon pro and everything else, but facebook won't display the image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to your existing codes:

```
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "my awesome caption in the EXTRA_TITLE field");
```

There is no clearly defined differences among EXTRA_TITLE, EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT. So there is no clear share protocol. We could always try them all. :-)

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Although the definition of Intent.EXTRA_TITLE is _A CharSequence dialog title to provide to the user when used with a ACTION_CHOOSER._ And Intent.EXTRA_TEXT _A constant CharSequence that is associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the literal data to be sent._

Comment: can u give me a link or example link so i can apply in my app.. thanks

Comment: Tech.Rahul, still need any help with this?

Comment: This doesnt work anymore. Facebook does not allow it

Comment: Doesn't work. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/ what a shame!

Answer (score 8):

This issue appear to be a long standing "feature" of the facebook app.  It's handling of intents has never been in a fully functional state.

Check the links on http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=93900

This needs to be elevated with the developers at facebook.  The reliance on hiding behind the Client API rather than fixing the obvious is working against them.

Comment: I true solution would have been a reply from a facebook representative, but since the lack of that, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: This link may clarify what's happening: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/ Facebook has no ears.