# Android : How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo-gallery

Hi guys I want a example or a link through that guidance want to know how to upload photos from device into facebook? Can anyone please provide me a solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214764/how-to-share-photo-with-caption-via-android-share-intent-on-facebook)

Comment: @Tapanparmar, its a 5 year old question..  anyway I know.. but didnt get more info so posted..

Comment: Ok yeah didn't saw that @Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does not use the conventional sharing-through-intent paradigm. The text you supply to share as caption is actually being used as the thumbnail link to share an online image or video.

This leaves no room for the caption. So don't waste you time looking for it.

You have to use Facebook API to share both image and the caption. Go to facebook developer page where you can find packages you'll need to include in your app (look for facebook.jar or similar).

Comment: Nar -- Thanks for helping.. I have gone through this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook this example.. So i can upload photos in facebook through my app.. :)

Comment: @TechEnd the link you provided is broken, can you update the link or add some tips to help finding the code you used, please?