# Share Image and text in twitter via intent in browser android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to share image and text  like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri u = Uri.parse(url);

        i.setData(u);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214764/how-to-share-photo-with-caption-via-android-share-intent-on-facebook)

Comment: No , it opens the native app , i want to open it in browser

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find the below code.

```
Uri path= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName()
    + "/drawable/" + "image_name");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Testing");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Using"));
```

Comment: I only want to tweet in browser ,   checked the above code , it using default in android device........