# How to share photos on facebook with android programmatically

Tags: android, facebook, photo, facebook-android-sdk

I follow facebook's tutorial and I want to share my application screen shot so i used code on below.But it didn't also i can be log in.

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                               .setBitmap(bm)
                                               .build();
                                       SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                               .addPhoto(photo)
                                               .build();

                                     ShareDialog shareDialog1 = new ShareDialog(Oyun.this);
                                     shareDialog1.show(content);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214764/how-to-share-photo-with-caption-via-android-share-intent-on-facebook)

Comment: they say  "It doesnt work anymore use facebook sdk"  but i couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit this answer given by this guy he share photos as well as include caption with it

[How to share photo with CAPTION via Android share intent on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214764/5476209)

You need to make a simple intent to Facebook for it and you can share it. Just go through the above answer and you will find it out very easy.